# Black screen problem

Tags: 18.04, screen

I have been using Ubuntu for the last two days and I have been in a big problem in the middle of it. I had a black screen problem when I installed Ubuntu then it was fixed.But again this problem is renewed today, whenever I switch on the computer then black screen is going on for some time, and not on, it becomes very pathetic thing, and I have to turn the switch off and then on again. Please tell how to solve it.

Comment: You are not giving us very much to work with here. **What version of Ubuntu are you running??** What graphics card/driver is installed in your system? What does it look like? When did this start? What have you tried to fix it so far, and did that change anything? Without more information, it is unlikely we will be able to help you.

Comment: 18.04 using, amd ryzen 2200g using, Mathorboard gigabyte a320m - s2h, after installing ubantu The problem is, when I turn on the computer, the screen goes black at times, It's happening two to three times a day, But once the computer is turned on properly, there is no problem.  So please help me.